# Get unique values in List of Lists

Tags: python, list, set, unique

I want to create a list (or set) of all unique values appearing in a list of lists in python.
I have something like this:

```
aList=[['a','b'], ['a', 'b','c'], ['a']]
```

and i would like the following:

```
unique_values=['a','b','c']
```

I know that for a list of strings you can just use set(aList), but I can't figure how to solve this in a list of lists, since set(aList) gets me the error message

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: You can flatten the list first. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+flatten+list (fyi, in Python these are called lists, not arrays)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know which one was correct ;)

Comment: I've seen list comprehensions doing that, but since my list is pretty big, i've guessed that in terms of efficiency that would be a bad call

Comment: You can use a generator expression to avoid creating a second list: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/. But you have to iterate over all elements in the nested lists, there is no way around that.

Comment: Related: [Union of multiple sets in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30773911/7851470)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
array = [['a','b'], ['a', 'b','c'], ['a']]
result = {x for l in array for x in l}
```

Comment: that did the job, thank you very much!
Isn't there a better way to do this kind of think without needing to iterate? (i'm a beginner but i thought that avoiding loops was the way to go when having a big len(array))

Comment: I am afraid there is no simpler way. You have a precisely defined input structure, you have a precisely defined output structure, and it's necessary to make the conversion. Since the conversion involves all elements it's necessary to "visit" all of them. Well, there are many different ways to obtain the result (see other posts) but the iteration is always present internally.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)'s [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten your array and then call [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?#set) on it:

```
from itertools import chain

array = [['a','b'], ['a', 'b','c'], ['a']]
print set(chain(*array))
```

If you are expecting a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#list) object:

```
print list(set(chain(*array)))
```

Comment: i've just created my account, can't raise anything yet :( Your answer was very helpful, but ive accepted the first answer. when i have enough point (or idk what gives permition to raise answers) i'll do it for yours

Comment: @mihasa No worries. I'm glad my answer was helpful.

Comment: Just got it... raised!

Comment: There's also `set(chain.from_iterable(array))`.

Answer (score 4):

```
array = [['a','b'], ['a', 'b','c'], ['a']]
unique_values = list(reduce(lambda i, j: set(i) | set(j), array))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [numpy.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy
import operator
print numpy.unique(reduce(operator.add, [['a','b'], ['a', 'b','c'], ['a']]))
# ['a' 'b' 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

The 2 top voted answers did not work for me, I'm not sure why (but I have integer lists). In the end I'm doing this:

```
unique_values = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in aList)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this.

```
array = [['a','b'], ['a', 'b','c'], ['a']]
res=()
for item in array:
    res = list(set(res) | set(item))
print res
```

Output:

```
['a', 'c', 'b']
```