# Convert a list of lists into a set of lists in Python 3

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of lists, and I want to turn it into a set of lists, in order to compare it with other sets.

For example, I want to do:

```py
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
myset = set(mylist)
myset
```

And get:

```py
{[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]}
```

But this error pops up:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:/Users/.../Testfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    myset = set(mylist)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I also tried this, a solution posted at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773911/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773911/union-of-multiple-sets-in-python):

```py
myset = set(x for lst in mylist for x in lst)
print(myset)
```

But this merges all of the internal lists.

```py
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Is there a way to convert `mylist` into a set of lists?

Comment: @Hari The problem with that is that it only works with lists of hashable items, and a list isn't hashable, as the error message points out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lists are not hashable in python. Instead, map to tuples, which are hashable:

```
>>> mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> set(map(tuple, mylist))
{(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)}
>>> set(tuple(x) for x in mylist)
{(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)}
```

You can also use a clean set comprehension here as well:

```
>>> {tuple(x) for x in mylist}
{(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Would you be confortable turning your arrays into tuples?

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
myset = set()

for array in mylist:
  myset.add(tuple(array))

print(myset)
```

This gives you: `{(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)}`