# Python: Extract list from inside the list and remove duplicates

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column that consists of lists of lists (of varying length).
One example:
`df['east'][0]` gives

```
[array(['Indonesia', 'New Zealand'], dtype=object), array(['Indonesia', 'New Zealand'], dtype=object)]
```

I want to merge the lists inside of this bigger list and get rid of duplicates and make sure that data is presented clearly, i.e. simply

```
['Indonesia', 'New Zealand']
```

I tried [some suggestions from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565759/get-unique-values-in-list-of-lists-in-python) to remove duplicates, but, for example,for `np.unique(functools.reduce(operator.add, east))` Python said "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (13,)"

I could usually solve problems, but here I am not sure what is happening - what are these arrays in the list.

Comment: removing duplicates from list is easy: convert it to set and if need convert back to list:
`
a=[1,2,2,3]
b=[set(a)]
print(b)
`
as result b will be [1,2,3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach would be to flatten your lists/arrays with a comprehension and then use `list(set())` to get unique values in a list:

```
df['east'].apply(lambda x: list(set(item for sublist in x for item in sublist)))
# example output: ['New Zealand', 'Indonesia']
```

Comment: mostly in python, `([` is fine, but not pretty. you can just do `set(item for sublist in x for item in sublist)`. you're not then creating an intermediate list that you immediately discard.

Comment: glad you took it into consideration. you already had my upvote because it was a good answer regardless.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following one liner to achieve your results.

```
df['east'].apply(lambda value: reduce(lambda a, x: list(set(list(a) + list(x))), value, []))
```

lets break it down...

`list(a) + list(x)` = avoids shape error and adds to lists to return one list (you can use addition of np arrays directly if you keep the shapes same)

`list(set(list(a) + list(x)))` = array of all unique elements by first taking their set.

`reduce(lambda a, x: list(set(list(a) + list(x))), value, []))` = recursively adds accumulator and the variable list to reduce it into one single list.