# Getting unique values from pandas column of 2d array cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where each cell in a column is a 2d array of items.

EX: Observation 1 has column `items` with values `['Baseball', 'Glove','Snack']`

When I use `.unique` on the individual cells, each cell gets analyzed based on the whole arrays value, not individual values in the array.

How can I iterate through each array in each cell to determine the true unique amount of items in the column? Thanks

```
  Items
0 ['Baseball', 'Hockey Stick', 'Mit']
1 ['Mit', 'Tennis Racket']
2 ['Baseball', 'Helmet']
```

These all return as unique values, I would like to get the unique count for each value in each list.

Comment: "I have a pandas DataFrame where each cell in a column is a 2d array of items." then you almost certainly shouldn't be using pandas. Store only scalar values in cells. Pandas is just not geared for this, use numpy if possible or just go back to base Python and drop all the added complexity.

Comment: This is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565759/get-unique-values-in-list-of-lists-in-python. Just replace the list with `df.Items`

Comment: Yes, I understand to only store scalar values in cells, however this is a homework problem. Not real world case.

Comment: Your homework _requires_ you to use pandas with numpy arrays in each cell? That doesn't make sense. What I'm saying is that if you have come to this approach and it's not a requirement, you will want to rethink the approach.

Comment: The requirement is to find unique values however possible. The data was given with an array in each column cell, this is all i know.

Comment: what exactly do you want? what i understand is this: `from collections import OrderedDict` and `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.Items))).keys())`

Comment: Ok, so this data should never have been put in a dataframe. As a data structure, it just doesn't fit the problem. Take a step back and give the raw data

Comment: Can you add your expected output? I'm still confused about what you need here, and whether you need counts or unique items, or both

Comment: I figured it out, I just used a double for loop to iterate through. The one liners sometimes are too complex

Comment: Great that you figured it out, that's pretty valuable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `chain` method of `itertools` together with `set`s as to solve the problem as follows.

```
# you have a dataframe called data with the column items.

from itertools import chain
unique_lists_in_items = data.items.unique().tolist()
set_of_items = set(chain(*unique_lists_in_items))
```

`set_of_items` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.unique` and `np.concatenate` on the column of interest. I have made an example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruits':(np.array(['banana', 'apple']), np.array(['cherry', 'apple']))})
#   items
#0  [banana, apple]
#1  [cherry, apple]
np.concatenate(df.fruits.values) #.values accesses the numpy array representation of the column
#array(['banana', 'apple', 'cherry', 'apple'],
#      dtype='<U6')
np.unique(np.concatenate(df.fruits.values)) #unique items
#array(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
#      dtype='<U6')
np.unique(np.concatenate(df.fruits.values), return_counts=True) #counts
#(array(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
#   dtype='<U6'), array([2, 1, 1]))
subset = df.fruits.dropna() # getting rid of NaNs
subset.loc[subset.map(len)!=0] #get rid of zero-length arrays
#0    [banana, apple]
#1    [cherry, apple]
#Name: fruits, dtype: object
np.unique(np.concatenate(subset.loc[subset.map(len)!=0].values), return_counts=True) #This works as desired
#(array(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
   dtype='<U6'), array([2, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: I don't understand how this gives a count?

Comment: What if the array in the cell is empty?

Comment: This should tolerate empty cells. For a count you can simply take the length of the array of unique values. Hope I understood that correctly.

Comment: Well, 'apple' appears twice originally, but only once in the output. So all counts will be 1

Comment: Oh, I guess I did not read the edited question. Let me update the solution.

Comment: ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Comment: Yup, figureing that out now, as well. A quick hack would be to filter those out. This solution also does not tolerate NaNs. Lemme update

Comment: Check out the updated version! Could be faster to use subset.str.len() instead of subset.map(len) but probably not a concern given that your homework problem is a  small size.