# using unique function in pandas for a 2D array

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637336/numpy-unique-with-order-preserved) question's answer I got the idea of using pandas unique function instead of numpy unique. When looking into the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) I discovered that this can only be done for 1D arrays or tuples. As my data has the format:

```
example = [[25.1, 0.03], [25.1, 0.03], [24.1, 15]]
```

it would be possible to covert it to tuples and after using the unique function again back to an array. Does someone know a 'better' way to do this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189818/getting-unique-values-from-pandas-column-of-2d-array-cells) question might be related, but is dealing with cells. I don't want to use numpy as I have to keep the order in the array the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to tuple and the convert to unique list:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, example)))
```

Output:

```
[(25.1, 0.03), (24.1, 15)]
```

Comment: Just noting this nearly a thousand times faster than using pandas:
`%timeit list(dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, example)))` -> `1.25 µs`

`%timeit pd.DataFrame(example).drop_duplicates()` -> `1.49 ms`

Comment: Well, as this would have been the only reason to use pandas for me, this is definitely the better option. Less dependencies is always good.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use Pandas:
To find the unique pairs in `example`, use `DataFrame` instead of `Series` and then `drop_duplicates`:

```
pd.DataFrame(example).drop_duplicates()

      0      1
0  25.1   0.03
2  24.1  15.00
```

(And `.values` will give you back a 2-D array.)